# int() argument must be a string or a number

Tags: python, list, int

I got an error. I did quick googling and it did not help me well.

I added the whole code, well kind of whole code. request from a user.

```
from derp_node import *

##############################################################################
# parse
############################################################################## 

def parse(tokens, i = 0):
    """parse: tuple(String) * int -> (Node, int)
    From an infix stream of tokens, and the current index into the
    token stream, construct and return the tree, as a collection of Nodes, 
    that represent the expression.

    NOTE:  YOU ARE NOT ALLOWED TO MUTATE 'tokens' (e.g. pop())!!!  YOU
        MUST USE 'i' TO GET THE CURRENT TOKEN OUT OF 'tokens'
    """
    if tokens == []:
        raise TypeError("Error: Empty List.")
    elif tokens[int(i)] == '*':
        tokens.remove(int(i))
        return mkMultiplyNode(parse(tokens), parse(tokens))
    elif tokens[int(i)] == '//':
        tokens.remove(int(i))
        return mkDivideNode(parse(tokens), parse(tokens))
    elif tokens[int(i)] == '+':
        tokens.remove(int(i))
        return mkAddNode(parse(tokens), parse(tokens))
    elif tokens[int(i)] == '-':
        tokens.remove(int(i))
        return mkSubtractNode(parse(tokens), parse(tokens))
    elif tokens[int(i)].isdigit():
        return mkLiteralNode(tokens.remove(int(i)))
    elif not tokens[int(i)].isdigit():
        return mkVariableNode(tokens.remove(int(i)))
    else:
        raise TypeError("Error: Invalid Input")

##############################################################################
# main
##############################################################################

def main():
    """main: None -> None
    The main program prompts for the symbol table file, and a prefix 
    expression.  It produces the infix expression, and the integer result of
    evaluating the expression"""

    print("Hello Herp, welcome to Derp v1.0 :)")

    inFile = input("Herp, enter symbol table file: ")
    symTbl = {}
    for line in open(inFile):
        i = line.split()
        symTbl[i[0]] = int(i[1])
    print("Derping the symbol table (variable name => integer value)...")
    for variable in sorted(symTbl):
        print(variable + " => " + str(symTbl[variable]))

    # STUDENT: CONSTRUCT AND DISPLAY THE SYMBOL TABLE HERE

    print("Herp, enter prefix expressions, e.g.: + 10 20 (RETURN to quit)...")

    # input loop prompts for prefix expressions and produces infix version
    # along with its evaluation
    while True:
        prefixExp = input("derp> ")
        if prefixExp == "":
            break

        # STUDENT: GENERATE A LIST OF TOKENS FROM THE PREFIX EXPRESSION
        prefixLst = prefixExp.split()
        # STUDENT: CALL parse WITH THE LIST OF TOKENS AND SAVE THE ROOT OF 
        # THE PARSE TREE.
        tokens = []
        parseLst = parse(prefixLst, tokens)
        # STUDENT: GENERATE THE INFIX EXPRESSION BY CALLING infix AND SAVING
        # THE STRING    
        infixLst = infix(parseLst)

        print("Derping the infix expression:")

        # STUDENT: EVALUTE THE PARSE TREE BY CALLING evaluate AND SAVING THE
        # INTEGER RESULT

        print("Derping the evaluation:")

    print("Goodbye Herp :(")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

The error I received is:

```
  File "derpNew.py", line 31, in parse
    if tokens[int(i)] == '*':
TypeError: int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'list'
```

If I remove the int() from the variable `i`, then I would get this error: `TypeError: list indices must be integers, not list`

Am I suppose to convert the list to tuple? Any help would be great. Thank you.

If you guys are curious how I am calling the parse. I put this under main function.

```
    tokens = []
    parseLst = parse(tokens, i)
```

**EDIT:**
The loop:

```
while True:
    prefixExp = input("derp> ")
    if prefixExp == "":
        break
    prefixLst = prefixExp.split()
    tokens = []
    parseLst = parse(tokens, i)
```

Comment: What are you passing to the `parse()` method as a second parameter? Apparently, a list while it should be an integer number. I'm simply repeating whatever interpreter has already told you... but you didn't listen..

Comment: `int([])` will cause this error: thus, *verify* the object passed to `int` (and figure out why it is so) as it is likely not as expected.

Comment: (trying to read minds): Probably you want to do `for i in ilist` or something along the lines?

Comment: @sashkello why not loop over the integer list ( if there is one! )

Comment: Have you defined `i`? This is where your error is and you are still not showing the whole code.

Comment: @sashkello I edited the post. I posted the whole code, kind of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`parseLst = parse(tokens, i)` - this line doesn't make sense unless you define `i`. If you want to pass default `i=0`, then just leave it out: `parseLst = parse(tokens)`.

EDIT: After the whole code has been pasted, there is some (apparently irrelevant) `i` defined before, which is why there was no NameError.

Comment: Thanks. Also, when I edited that. I got another error. Same line, however I got this:File "derpNew.py", line 40, in parse   tokens.remove(int(i))   ValueError: list.remove(x): x not in list'

Comment: @Singh2013 As before, interpreter tells you the exact reason. It can't remove `x` from the list because it is not there in the first place.

Comment: I put this in the input ' + 10 * x y ' Then it should print out (10 + ( x * y )), so basically taking all the user input and puts them in tuple and then parse it.

Comment: @Singh2013 Well, firstly I don't see the connection between the input and the output. Secondly, if you have another specific question - then ask it, because I can't rewrite the whole code for you, mate.

Answer (score 0):

The passed variable `i` is a `list`, that's why the errors! Would need more info on the arguments being passed to help you more!

List indices work like this

```
>>> my_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>>> for index in range(5):
...    print my_list[i]
1
2
3 
4
5
>>> my_list[3]
4
```

Answer (score 0):

What are you passing to the method `parse(...)` as **second** parameter? If it's a list, it shouldn't. You may want to change the value you are passing to `parse`.

You may also want to check if `tokens` is an empty list, before the other `ifs`, or it will cause another error.

```
if tokens == []:
    raise TypeError("Error: Empty List.")
elif tokens[int(i)] == '*':
    tokens.remove(int(i))
    return mkMultiplyNode(parse(tokens), parse(tokens))
    return mkSubtractNode(parse(tokens), parse(tokens))
elif tokens[int(i)].isdigit():
    return mkLiteralNode(tokens.remove(int(i)))
elif not tokens[int(i)].isdigit():
    return mkVariableNode(tokens.remove(int(i)))
else:
    raise TypeError("Error: Invalid Input")
```